# How to mock NavParams in tests?

Tags: unit-testing, angular, ionic2, angular2-testing

*This might be an Ionic 2 only question, as I don't see NavParams in the Angular 2 docs, but some concepts might translate so I tagged both.*

Given that I call `navparams.get('somekey')` in order to listen to parameters that are passed in, it's tricky to mock the NavParams in tests.

For example, here's how I currently do it:

```
export class NavParamsMock {
  public get(key): any {
    return String(key) + 'Output';
  }
}
```

This works for really basic tests, but what if I had a component that I have to test that it `gets` a specific type of `Object`, eg a `User`.

Then, I can do something like

```
export class NavParamsMock {
  public get(key): any {
    if (key === 'user') {
       return new User({'name':'Bob'})
    }
    return String(key) + 'Output';
  }
}
```

But, this doesn't work if you want to use the `get(user)` in another test, or even another component's spec. Say you use NavParams in 2 different components, and they both expect different result when you do `get(user)`, it becomes increasingly tricky to mock.

Has anyone found a solution to this scenario?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can get value of your choice by implementing your own setter method.

```
export class NavParamsMock {
  static returnParam = null;
  public get(key): any {
    if (NavParamsMock.returnParam) {
       return NavParamsMock.returnParam
    }
    return 'default';
  }
  static setParams(value){
    NavParamsMock.returnParam = value;
  }
}
```

Then in each test you can access the service and set your own params object.

```
beforeEach(() => {
  NavParamsMock.setParams(ownParams); //set your own params here
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    providers: [
      {provide: NavParams, useClass: NavParamsMock},
    ]
  });
})
```

Comment: I'm getting a "Property returnParams does not exist on type 'NavParamsMock'... Nevermind you missed an s after the returnParams.

Comment: there was a typo. ``returnParam``

Answer (score 7):

Rather than mocking out the class, it's easiest to just create an instance of the `NavParams` class, then use it. `NavParams` makes the `data` property publicly assignable, so it can be modified in each test as needed.

The below example assumes your page looks something like this:

```
@IonicPage()
@Component({...})
export class YourPage {
  private data: string;

  constructor(navParams: NavParams) {
    this.data = navParams.get('data');
  }
}
```

I.e., you call `navParams.get()` in your page `constructor`, `ionViewDidLoad()`, `ngOnInit()`, or similar initializer function. In this case, to modify the `NavParams` data and ensure it's used properly, you need to modify your test injected `navParams.data` property, then regenerate your page:

```
import {IonicModule, NavParams} from 'ionic-angular';
import {ComponentFixture, TestBed} from '@angular/core/testing';

describe('YourPage', () => {
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<YourPage>;
  let component: YourPage;
  const data = {data: 'foo'};
  const navParams = new NavParams(data);

  function generateFixture() {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(YourPage);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  }

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [YourPage],
      imports: [
        IonicModule.forRoot(YourPage),
      ],
      providers: [
        {provide: NavParams, useValue: navParams},
      ]
    });
    generateFixture();
  });

  describe('NavParams', () => {
    it('should use injected data', () => {
      expect(component['data']).toEqual('foo');
    });
    it('should use new injected data', () => {
      const newData = {data: 'bar'};
      navParams.data = newData;
      generateFixture();
      expect(component['data']).toEqual('bar');
    });
  });
});
```

If your page calls `navParams.get('key')` everywhere instead of assigning to a private member, then simply reassigning the `navParams.data` property is sufficient in each test (no need to call `generateFixture()` each time).

Comment: This doesn't work if I have 20 specs requiring different nav params. I'd like to dynamically set nav params inside each spec to suit each test case.

Comment: The `data` property on `NavParams` is public and can be set in each test if desired. Assuming you access members in data in `NavParams` in the constructor of your page, you'll need to recreate your page in order to test the new data was used. But if you always access the data in `NavParams` directly without assigning to local members, then simply reassigning the data property of `NavParams` is all that is required. I've updated my answer to match.

Answer (score 4):

I modified @raj's answer with my own variation of this technique. @raj's only allow you to set one parameter. Mine allows for key value storage with multiple parameters.

```
export class NavParamsMock {
  static returnParams: any = {};

  public get(key): any {
    if (NavParamsMock.returnParams[key]) {
       return NavParamsMock.returnParams[key];
    }
    return 'No Params of ' + key + ' was supplied. Use NavParamsMock.setParams('+ key + ',value) to set it.';
  }

  static setParams(key,value){
    NavParamsMock.returnParams[key] = value;
  }
}
```

Comment: The Property `data` is missing.This is how it's done: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44658048/mocking-out-navparams-in-ionic3-gives-back-property-data-is-missing-in-type-type

Comment: @nottinhill is this some ionic 3 change? So with my implementation above, I need to `extends NavParams` ?

Comment: Yes you can extend, but I mock it all out, gives me full control.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example with multiple params

**NavParamsMock**

```
export class NavParamsMock {

  static returnParams: any = {}

  public get (key): any {
    if (NavParamsMock.returnParams[key]) {
      return NavParamsMock.returnParams[key]
    }
  }

  static setParams (key, value): any {
    NavParamsMock.returnParams[key] = value
  }

}
```

Add to **TestBed** providers the following

```
{provide: NavParams, useClass: NavParamsMock}
```

**Unit test**

```
it('i am a unit test', () => {
    const navParams = fixture.debugElement.injector.get(NavParams)

    navParams.get =
      jasmine
        .createSpy('get')
        .and
        .callFake((param) => {
          const params = {
            'param1': 'value',
            'param2':  'value'
          }
          return params[param]
        })


    comp.ionViewDidLoad()
  })
```