# Mocking out NavParams in Ionic3 gives back Property Data is missing in type typeOf NavParams

Tags: unit-testing, ionic-framework, ionic2

```
export class NavParamsMock {

    static returnParam = null;
    public get(key): any {
        if (NavParamsMock.returnParam) {
            return NavParamsMock.returnParam
        }
        return 'default';
    }
    static setParams(value){
        NavParamsMock.returnParam = value;
    }
}
```

It's not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error notes the data is missing from your class so it fails.

If you don't care and want to avoid these kind of errors then extend your class.

```
export class NavParamsMock extends NavParams
```

This will fill in the missing properties.

If you don't want to extend the full class you can just the data property as the error says

```
export class NavParamsMock {
    static returnParam = null;
    get data(){ return NavParamsMock.returnParam; }
    set data(params) { NavParamsMock.returnParam = params; } 
    public get(key): any {
        if (NavParamsMock.returnParam) {
            return NavParamsMock.returnParam
        }
        return 'default';
    }
    static setParams(value){
        NavParamsMock.returnParam = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! As a bonus, how would you set a key? `navParamsMock.set({"header": "blue"});` ?

Comment: setParams is the name I believe you named it as. Or by directly going towards the object returnParam

Comment: Looks my copy-pasted implementation of NavParamsMock is faulty. We need key-value pairs with NavParams.

Comment: https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/9331 I believe this will clarify